# make a .deb package for a compiled source

Tags: linux, debian, compile

since I'm a noob at Linux and programming...etc (I know almost nothing in programming and compiling) I downloaded the qbittorrent 3.5.1 stable source I followed the instructions here >>https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Compiling-qBittorrent-on-Debian-and-Ubuntu<< did everything compiled successfully Installed successfully and working greatly but I wish to make a .deb package to the compiled source, How do I make it please?
I'm a Debian user 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a .deb package use the checkinstall package.

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall -D # -R for RPM, -S for slackware packages, -A to set package arch.
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more. Details like where the command should be run and what it does etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

1. go to packages.debian.org and look for qbittorent
2. get the debianized source for release you have, I use testing ( Jessie ) so it more or less safe to take source packaged in sid ( unstable ), If I would use stable I would take source packaged in stable or testing.

   dget -ux http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qbittorrent/qbittorrent_3.1.3-1.dsc
3. get the newest source code from the upstream:

   wget https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/archive/release-3.1.5.tar.gz
4. use `uupdate` from devscripts package to debianize the new upstream's source

assuming that release-3.1.5.tar.gz and debian package are in the same directory

```
cd qbittoren-3.1.3/
uupdate ../release-3.1.5.tar.gz
```

5. after that you need to `cd ../qbittorrent-3.1.5`

and build the package `debuild -us-uc`

of course you'll need to install  all dependencies in order to build the source.

after it is finished I have the following debian packages:

```
ls -1 ../*.deb
../qbittorrent_3.1.5-1_amd64.deb
../qbittorrent-dbg_3.1.5-1_amd64.deb
../qbittorrent-nox_3.1.5-1_amd64.deb
```

the commands used without description:

```
mkdir qbittorent
cd qbittorent
dget -ux http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qbittorrent/qbittorrent_3.1.3-1.dsc
wget https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/archive/release-3.1.5.tar.gz
cd qbittorrent-3.1.3
uupdate ../release-3.1.5.tar.gz
cd ../qbittorrent-3.1.5
debuild -us -uc
```

Done.

Comment: after reading the question again I see that you want to make debian from already compiled source. sure you can do it, but making a real package as described above is a better solution.